# Screenshots on Nexus 7 are 0 bytes

Tags: nexus-7, screenshots

I am taking screen shots for testing an app. on Nexus 7. Yesterday I could take the screen shots perfectly. Today when I press <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Volume Down</kbd> together it makes the screenshot sound but gives me .png with 0 bytes. What happened, and how do I fix this?

Comment: I am just running into exactly the same problem, also on a Nexus 7, also when testing an app, also when screenshots used to work just minutes ago.

Comment: After disconnecting and reconnecting the USB of my device, the screenshot files suddenly are there again and contain data. New screenshots (taking after replugging) are shown as having 0 bytes again, though.

Comment: Related [Android SE post](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46315/119358)

Answer (score 1):

If you take screen shots with the Nexus 7 connected to your computer the screen shot images don't seem to update in Windows Explorer correctly (they show as 0 bytes) and they are not viewable.

The fix is to unplug then plug your USB cable back in and they will show up with the correct size and be viewable.  Either that or unplug your USB cable before taking the screen shots then plug it in to download them.

I guess this is a feature?  It is certainly annoying because I keep forgetting about the fix and wondering why my screenshots are 0 bytes.