# Hidden (dot-files — ".*") files not presented by MTP

Tags: mtp

Files starting with the `.` character (hidden files under linux/unix/OSX conventions) are not being displayed when connected to a Galaxy Stratosphere II via either Android File Transfer or simple-mtpfs.  I've got more than ten such files in the root directory of my SD Card and none of them are being displayed.

This may be a related question: [Not all files are visible over MTP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/not-all-files-are-visible-over-mtp)

However, that question doesn't mention anything about dot-files, which seem to be my issue here.  Is this a known issue or a "feature" of the MTP protocol?

Comment: I suppose it's just how Android handles files and folders. If it is invisible then it won't give you any data about it via MTP. Mass storage may show the file/folder but MTP is managed by Android so it does not have to.

Comment: The files are visible using `ls -a` from the command line in the phone's Terminal Emulator app.

Comment: Then it's just Android no showing you hidden files/folders via MTP. Nothing you can do about that.