# How can I backup my contacts and get them back?

Tags: contacts, backup

My question might sound stupid, but I want to backup my contacts, so even when I lost the phone or deleted the contacts, or factory reset the phone, I can still have the contacts. I never backup contacts before, so pls offer a detailed guide, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use google contacts sync. to backup online, so your contacts will be safe there.

Read more at
https://www.google.com/sync/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1. open dialer/contacts
   2.choose import/export by clicking on top right corner
   3.click Export to .vcf file

Answer (score 0):

I recommend one of these two free Android apps, both of which I find easy to use:

1. [Red Rock Backup Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.uia.android.backupcontacts), which exports to Google CSV, Outlook
   CSV, or a custom CSV, and has no builtin restore (You can easily
   restore using [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/)).
2. [OBSS MCBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.globile.mycontactbackup) exports to [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcard)
   (one file per contact) and does have builtin restore.

Both of these apps export files that can be imported into most contact managers (not just Android ones).

You'll want to export the files created by these apps somewhere off your phone. For that, you have two options:

1. Use either of these apps to email the exported contacts to yourself.
2. Use a USB cord to get the contacts on your computer. Steps:

   1. Use one of the above apps to export the contacts onto your phone's SD card.
   2. Restart the phone to deal with [a bug](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46321) in Android.
   3. Plug your phone into a computer with a USB cable.
   4. Open your phone's storage in your file manager (eg. Windows Explorer or Finder)
   5. Copy the backup files to your computer. For OBSS MCBackup, you want the folder com.vcast.mediamanager/contacts. For Red Rock Backup Contacts, the file you want is called Backup.Contacts.*.csv by default.