# How do I export all contacts (names and phone numbers) to a text file on SD card offline?

Tags: contacts, backup

How do I export all contacts (phone, SIM) with phone numbers to a text file on SD card? Without Google, without connected computer, without network. Just save everything to a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is function integrated into build-in Contacts app.

1. Open Contacts
2. Switch to "Contacts" tab
3. Press the tree-dots button at the bottom
4. "Import/Export"
5. Export to storage
6. Check all checkboxes
7. Check file like `00002.vcf`

This is a vCard file. One can manually open it in a text editor and search for contact names and phone numbers even if no special program for vCard is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to export all contacts to a single file, I recommend [Red Rock Backup Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.uia.android.backupcontacts), which exports to Google CSV, Outlook CSV, or a custom CSV. It has no builtin restore feature, so you might need to connect to a network to restore them again with [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/).

If you don't mind multiple files, I also recommend [OBSS MCBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.globile.mycontactbackup), which exports to [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcard) (one file per contact) and does have builtin restore.

Both of these are easy to use and are free, and both of these apps export files that can be imported into most contact managers (not just Android ones).

Note that files created by these apps, like all Android files, are subject to [a bug](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46321) where you may need to restart android before they are visible over [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) to transfer to your computer.