# Slow loading of the internal storage folder in PC

Tags: internal-storage, usb-connection-mode

Slow loading of the internal storage folder specifically when I connect my phone to the PC. A green bar keeps on progressing quickly at the beginning and seems to be slowing down as it reaches the end and still the folders don't appear. I am not able to transfer the files from my phone to the PC.

Please help.

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS, it's considered as shouting which is rude and hard to read.

Comment: MTP is a very dump and slow protocol but it should come to an end loading the folder. Try to reboot the phone. Also make sure the `/sdcard` shared folder does not contain too many files (less than may be ~1000).

Comment: i did but still it didn't work .

Comment: Then I would enable developer options, enable ADB and install a minimal ADB set-up on your PC. This allows you to access the phone via ADB shell and upload/download files to/from the PC. It should not suffer from any performance problems. Using ADB shell you can clean up the sdcard folder. May be then MTP works again. You can also try to clear the Android Media store https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/not-all-files-are-visible-over-mtp

Answer (score 1):

Issue you're facing is mostly because of either of these two reasons:

1. MTP acts retarded when there are too many files
2. Windows acts dumb sometimes (switch to linux)

I don't really have a solution to either than switching to linux (as i did) for the latter

Now some REAL workaround to HELP you:

1. Connect Your phone and computer to same WiFi/hotspot or even connect your pc to the same mobile's hotspot
2. Download MixPlorer or any other file manager with FTP on your android device

then follow this guide

https://manyandroid.app/android-ftp-file-transfer-mixplorer/

Trust me learning to transfer file this way would just be a one time investment, this setup will help you forever!