# File explorer shows empty folder

Tags: usb, file-transfer

I am trying to remove all the images and videos accumulated by whats app over a year
I have been doing the same thing since 2012 ...

I browse to This folder after connecting my android:

**PC\myPhone\Internal storage\Android\media\com.whatsapp\WhatsApp\Media\WhatsApp Images**

But on my PC the file explorer shows this folder as empty when its clearly not...

[image]

I tried doing a phone backup using smart switch - it failed...

I suspect its a bug when there are too many files?
anyone encountered same issue?

from android file explorer there is content in this folder:
[image]

I can see and interact with the images in other folders
But once I try to open a the folder with the 900 files or more it thinks about it and crashes, after that I'm not able to view any files, only folder structure.

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround using this [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/not-all-files-are-visible-over-mtp)  (Thank you @user:44325 Andrew )
The workaround was to move the folder to the root location of the phone using the android file explorer
But the original Issue is still there...

[image]

Comment: is this issue being faced in the other folders with less number of files

Comment: no, other folders are working fine! I think there is some bug when the folder is loaded with files.

Comment: does it load when you open other folder with many files?

Comment: Possibly related: [Not all files are visible over MTP](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46315/44325)

Comment: Thank you! It seems very similar, but this might be a long path names issue.... I was able to use one of the reply there as a workaround.  see updated question.

Comment: your update looks like you are going to lose data.. did you "move" directory from windows MTP? this might end horrible don't interrupt it accidentially. next time use adb command line

Comment: You are 100% correct I usually do copy then delete from android.... this time it was successful

Comment: To access this location, it does not require root. Why not use any other file explorer like solid explorer or MiXplorer from XDA? Could be a bug with built -in file explorer //On Pixel 4a, Android 12 I can see all of them using built - in file explorer but then I don't have more than 30 odd videos//Of course, I am talking of using Android only without connecting to laptop

Comment: I thought the issue might be because for path is too long, but after counting the characters in the example you left (and adding to it an average WA image file name), the character number is 109 characters, which leaves a lot of overhead to the party limit of 260 characters.  Have you tried scanning the memory card for errors?

Comment: its not on a memory card, its on the phone itself, see update, once i moved the folder to root of "internal" it worked.

Comment: I think your suspect is true. I recommend adb pull instead. you could also try [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync) or [winadb](https://gitlab.com/aIecxs/winadb-sync)